# Angular custom form validation message not showing up on 1 specific field

Tags: angular, validation

I've got an Angular form with (amongst others) 2 elements that look like this:

Postcode:

```html
<label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : registrationForm.postcode.$invalid && (registrationForm.postcode.$dirty || submitted)}">
    <span class="input-label">Postcode<span class="required">*</span></span>
    <input ng-change="test()" name="postcode" type="text" ng-model="registration.postcode" required ng-pattern="postcode_regex" autocomplete='postal-code'>
</label>
<p ng-show="profileForm.postcode.$invalid && (profileForm.postcode.$dirty || submitted)" class="assertive">A valid postcode is required.</p>
```

Phone:

```html
<label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : registrationForm.telephone.$invalid && (registrationForm.telephone.$dirty || submitted)}">
    <span class="input-label">Telephone<span class="required">*</span></span>
    <input ng-change="test()" name="telephone" type="tel" ng-model="registration.telephone" required ng-pattern="phone_number_regex" autocomplete='tel'>
</label>
<p ng-show="registrationForm.telephone.$invalid && (registrationForm.telephone.$dirty || submitted)" class="assertive">A valid telephone is required (numbers only please).</p>
```

The relevant controller code looks like this:

```javascript
$scope.phone_number_regex = /^[0-9 ]{10,}$/;
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation
// (Note: I tested this on regex101.com and it works fine).
$scope.postcode_regex = /^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$/; 

$scope.submit = function (isValid) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if (isValid) {
```

etc.

When the user completes the telephone field the validation message (i.e. "A valid telephone is required etc...") appears once they start to type until it matches the `$scope.phone_number_regex`.  However on the postcode field no validation message (i.e. "A valid postcode is required.") is ever displayed, however the form won't submit until it matches the `$scope.postcode_regex`.

Why am I not seeing the validation message for postcode please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict with form names. Hope your are using `registrationForm` and not the `profileForm` here.

Change `profileForm.postcode.$invalid` to `registrationForm.postcode.$invalid` and `profileForm.postcode.$dirty` to `registrationForm.postcode.$dirty`

```html
<p ng-show="registrationForm.postcode.$invalid && (registrationForm.postcode.$dirty || submitted)" class="assertive">A valid postcode is required.</p>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks @coder!  I don't know how many times I read that and missed it!!

Comment: @Mr Benn glad to help you!